# Laravel routes not working with subfolder

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, routes, laravel-5.1

Using Laravel 5 migrated from 4.2 now laravel 5 is installed in subfolder "abc" do i have to write abc/warehouse for every route ? previously it was /warehouse.  i want to use all existing routes like /warehouse inside subdirectory abc.

i am on localhost xampp with port 81.  http://localhost:81/warehouse

any one here with quick solution

Answer (score 2):

You use `prefix` when defining routes:

```
Route::prefix('abc')->group(...)
```

[Route Prefixes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#route-group-prefixes)

```
Route::prefix('abc')->group(function () {
    Route::get('warehouse', function () { 
        // Matches The "/abc/warehouse" URL
     }); 
});
```

Ideally you should do it in the `RouteServiceProvider`

```
Route::middleware('web')
   ->prefix('abc')
   ->namespace($this->namespace)
   ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
```

This way everything in the routes file is prefixed and you dont need the extra group wrapping.

Here's the example from the 5.0 docs:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function() {
    Route::get('users', function() { 
        // Matches The "/admin/users" URL
     });
 });
```

Comment: thanks for answer but what about when i transfer my application to live server i have to change routes again ? i have more than 500 routes. any other solution ?

Comment: You can wrap all your routes with a group so its only one call.

Comment: Thanks i will give it a try. i appreciate your help

Comment: Opps... it gives me Method prefix does not exist.

Comment: Try `Route::group(['prefix => 'abc'], function() { ...})` instead

Comment: getting syntax error, unexpected 'abc' (T_STRING), expecting ']'

Comment: why don't just config your local web server point to the project/public ?      DocumentRoot "path_to_project/public"
     ServerName localhost
    <Directory "path_to_project/public">

Comment: its already pointing to public but e.g one form is submitting to /formpost. now because the files are inside abc folder i have to write /abc/formpost for each route ?

Comment: what is the "files" ? blade ? controller ? model ?

Comment: i think its working now with wrapping i am another quick question now its redirecting correctly but i want to access site through localhost/abc/warehouse but in this case its redirecting to localhost/warehouse and i have some other files in main directory...

Answer (score 2):

what you can do is add a line in `RouteServiceProvider` in `mapWebRoutes` function like this

```
public function mapWebRoutes()
{
    //default 
    Route::middleware('web')
             ->namespace($this->namespace)
             ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));

    //subfolder
    Route::middleware('web')
             ->prefix('abc')
             ->namespace($this->namespace)
             ->group(base_path('routes/abc.php'));
}
```

then create a file inside `routes/abc.php` and copy paste all your routes inside it

Route prefix https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#route-group-prefixes

For laravel 5.0 you have to wrap inside `Route::group`

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'abc', 'namespace' => 'Auth'], function(){
     //define all your routes here     
     Route::post('login', 'AuthController@login');

});
```

**Namespace:** Here i have define `Auth` in namespace that means my all controllers like `AuthController` files should be inside `app/Http/Controllers/Auth` folders.

Laravel route 5.0 https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/routing#route-group-prefixes

For laravel 5.0 namespace structure check this https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/structure

Comment: I think the easiest way is with .htaccess. can we do that with .htaccess ?

Comment: I am using laravel 5.0

Comment: this is the most easy, you don't have to do anything

Comment: if you are using 5.0 then you have to wrap inside `Route:group`

Comment: whats the namespace ? i am new to Laravel and just migrated from 4.2 version so really not sure about name space here. how can i get current namesapce ?

Comment: Namespace is defined at the top of the php file. I.e. App\Http\Controllers;

Comment: namespace is the path where your controller class will be. Suppose i have a controller class with namespace at top `namespace App\Http\Controllers\Abc` that means the controller file will be inside `app/Http/Controllers/Abc` folder

Comment: @DanishJamshed i have updated answer with namespace example check it. hope it may clear you

Comment: I have more than 500 routes i have to group each route with its group controller like you said for Auth controller. what about more than 50 other controllers ?

Comment: http://localhost:81/abc/warehouse is working but 

http://localhost:81/abc/warehousepost not working posting a form to this url
routs for both are 

Route::get('/warehouse', 'WarehouseController@index');

Route::post('/warehousepost', 'WarehouseController@indexpost');

Comment: do you have controllers in different folders ?

Comment: No in App\Http\Controllers

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174397/discussion-between-rkj-and-danish-jamshed).