# Laravel 8 and 9 API route from subfolder, does it still works?

Tags: laravel, api, nginx, subdirectory

I've just test the API using Postman. When I don't using sub-directory, the API works fine like this
[image]

But if I using sub-directory, it returns 404 Not Found, like this, even I configure `nano/etc/nginx/sites-available/mobilku` by adding this line following this link :
[Config nginx for Laravel In a subfolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27785372/config-nginx-for-laravel-in-a-subfolder)

```
location /mobilku {
    alias var/www/html/mobilku/public;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$args;
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippet/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```

the output when I using subfolder it return like this
[image]

the question is, how to make API routes from subfolder still works like picture in above?
Here is my example code for get car using API

```
Route::prefix('car')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', [CarController::class, 'all'])->name('car');
    Route::get('/details/{id}', [CarController::class, 'details'])->name('car.detail');
    Route::post('/search', [CarController::class, 'search'])->name('car.search');
    Route::post('/filter', [CarController::class, 'filter'])->name('car.filter');
});
```

I just read this link [Laravel routes not working with subfolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51186394/laravel-routes-not-working-with-subfolder), but I'm not sure that answer still works for Laravel 8 and 9.

Comment: Are there any static files (or PHP files other than `index.php`) that should be served from the user browser? Or this laravel app is a pure API app?

Comment: yes it's a pure API app in this project

Comment: your question is my answer!! thanks

Answer (score 2):

#### laravel web app configuration

According to the laravel [v8](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-group-prefixes) and [v9](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#route-group-prefixes) documentation, there are no big changes from the laravel [v5](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#route-group-prefixes) (besides that your routes should now start with the `/` prefix unlike it was in v5). Both answers from the referred [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51186394/laravel-routes-not-working-with-subfolder) also suggests to use a `RouteServiceProvider` ([v8](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Foundation/Support/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.html), [v9](https://laravel.com/api/9.x/Illuminate/Foundation/Support/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.html)) to define such a prefix globally.

However when you place your app under an additional URI prefix, it will see all the routes as `/mobilku/api/...` rather than `/api/...`, so you should change some other code part of your laravel app that you didn't show in your question to made it ready for such a change (or you can somewhat "spoof" the URI it will see from it's side; see the last part of the answer). You may also consider to just rename an `/api` URI prefix to the `/mobilku` one.

#### nginx configuration

Serving a PHP web app under an URI prefix using the `alias` directive is a bit tricky due the the long standing [side effects](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/97) of the `try_files` directive used together with the `alias` one, which are unlikely to be fixed at least until the major nginx version gets changed since there are too many configurations exists adopted to those effects in some way. Commonly used workarounds are:

- duplicating the `try_files` directive last argument prefix:

  ```
  location /mobilku {
      alias var/www/html/mobilku/public;
      try_files $uri $uri/ /mobilku/mobilku/index.php$args;
      location ~ \.php$ {
          include snippet/fastcgi-php.conf;
          fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
          fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
      }
  }
  ```
- using an `if` instead of the `try_files`:

  ```
  location /mobilku {
      alias var/www/html/mobilku/public;
      if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite ^ /mobilku/index.php last; }
      location ~ \.php$ {
          include snippet/fastcgi-php.conf;
          fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
          fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
      }
  }
  ```
- using an additional named location as the `try_files` directive last argument:

  ```
  location /mobilku {
      alias var/www/html/mobilku/public;
      try_files $uri $uri/ @mobilku;
      location ~ \.php$ {
          include snippet/fastcgi-php.conf;
          fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
          fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
      }
  }
  location @mobilku {
      rewrite ^ /mobilku/index.php last;
  }
  ```

However none of those workarounds are needed when you are serving an API web app that doen't have any static files at all, and any incoming request should be served by the `index.php` controller. The much more efficient way, without traversing the request though different location, checking the static files existence and matching an URI against the `\.php$` regex pattern (invoking an expensive PCRE library call) will be the following:

```
location /mobilku {
    root /var/www/html/mobilku/public;
    rewrite ^ /index.php break;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$uri;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
}
```

#### Spoofing a request URI that will be seen by the laravel app

An original request URI seen by laravel application is passed to the PHP-FPM backend via the `REQUEST_URI` FastCGI variable, which is being defined inside the `fastcgi_params` file as

```
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
```

If for some reason you can't change your backend laravel (or any other PHP based) web app, you still can change the `REQUEST_URI` FastCGI variable value that is being passed to the backend.

That [`$request_uri`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_request_uri) is an internal read-only nginx variable, so you can't change its value using `set` directive. However you can redefine its value **after** it will be defined inside the `fastcgi_params` file. The PHP-FPM FastCGI backend will use the last defined value (although other FastCGI backends can behave differently; you can check [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/512028/nginx-fcgiwrap-how-come-order-of-fastcgi-param-matters) ServerFault thread to find out more some details). To strip the `/mobilku` URI prefix from the `REQUEST_URI` FastCGI variabe you can use an additional `rewrite` directive:

```
location /mobilku {
    root /var/www/html/mobilku/public;
    rewrite /mobilku/?(.*) /$1;
    set $tweaked_uri $uri$is_args$args;
    rewrite ^ /index.php break;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI $tweaked_uri;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$uri;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
}
```

or the following one to replace the `/mobilku` prefix with the `/api`:

```
location /mobilku {
    root /var/www/html/mobilku/public;
    rewrite /mobilku/?(.*) /api/$1;
    set $tweaked_uri $uri$is_args$args;
    rewrite ^ /index.php break;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI $tweaked_uri;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$uri;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
}
```

However it can be unreliable if your original URI contain some characters that are getting url-decoded during the URI normalization process (for example, some special characters or two bytes UTF-8 characters from national alphabets) because the `rewrite` directive (as well as the `location` one) works with the normalized URI while a PHP backend expect to see an url-encoded one. A more reliable way would be to use a [`map`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html) block to strip or replace URI prefix, e.g.

```
map $request_uri $tweaked_uri {
    ~^/mobilku/?(.*)  /$1;
    default           $request_uri;
}
```

or

```
map $request_uri $tweaked_uri {
    ~^/mobilku/?(.*)  /api/$1;
    default           $request_uri;
}
```

Then you can use a mapped `$tweaked_uri` variable the same way as shown in the previous example:

```
location /mobilku {
    root /var/www/html/mobilku/public;
    rewrite ^ /index.php break;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI $tweaked_uri;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$uri;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The Laravel application understands that it is at the root of the server by default.

Try this, I hope it helps you:

source: https://lucabecchetti.medium.com/configure-laravel-to-work-in-a-subdirectory-and-with-artisan-serve-at-the-same-time-654ba0c1fd0b

Add APP_DIR environment variable to your .env file, containing the subdirectory where Laravel is installed into, like showed below:

```
APP_DIR = "laravel_subdir"
```

Then create a Helper Provider to define our custom functions, create a file HelperServiceProvider.php inside Providers directory, with the following code:

```
<?php
    namespace App\Providers;
    use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
    class HelperServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider{
    /**
    * Bootstrap services.
    *
    * @return void
    */
    public function boot(){
    }
    /**
    * Register services.
    *
    * @return void
    */
    public function register(){
      foreach (glob(app_path() . '/Helpers/*.php') as $file) {
        require_once($file);
      }
    }
}
```

Then, at the level of App directory, add Helpers directory, and inside it, create a file SubdirectoryAssetsHelper.php, with the following code:

```
<?php
    if (! function_exists('subdirAsset')) {
    function subdirAsset($path){
        return asset( (App::environment('production') ? env('APP_DIR') : '')."/".$path);
        }
    }
    if (! function_exists('subdirMix')) {
        function subdirMix($path){
            return mix( (App::environment('production') ? env('APP_DIR') : '')."/".$path);
        }
    }
```

Now register the provider by adding this line to config/app.php file:

```
App\Providers\HelperServiceProvider::class
```

Now replace the function mapWebRoutes of file RouteServiceProvider.php, like showed below:

```
/**
* Define the "web" routes for the application.
*
* These routes all receive session state, CSRF protection, etc.
*
* @return void
*/
protected function mapWebRoutes(){
    Route::prefix(App::environment('production') ? env('APP_DIR') : '')
    ->middleware('web')
    ->namespace($this->namespace)
    ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
}
```

And import App class in top of file:

use App;
That’s all, now you can use function subdirAsset instead of asset and subdirMix instead of mix inside your blade files.

Switch environment
If you are using valet or artisan serve, keep your APP_ENV variable to “local”:

```
APP_ENV = local
```

If you are in a production environment of shared hosting, use:

```
APP_ENV = production
```

Comment: Links have a tendency to die; please bring the important bits into your answer directly.